# Draggable BitmapField in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, graphics, bitmapfield

I am building an application where i need a BitmapField on top of the MapField. This BitmapField need to be Draggable i.e. when I click on the BitmapField and move the cursor, BitmapField should move without moving the map. Is it possible?? How can i do this..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public class Def extends MainScreen
{
VerticalFieldManager vertical;
BitmapField bitmapField;
int px=0,py=0;
public Def() 
{
    vertical=new VerticalFieldManager()
    {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) 
        {
            super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
            setExtent(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
        }       
    };
    vertical.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("background.png")));//put here map image;

    bitmapField=new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("rectanagle.png"));//For moving give small image;
    vertical.add(bitmapField);
    add(vertical);

}

protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time) 
{
    px=px+dx;
    py=py+dy;
    XYEdges xyEdges=new XYEdges(py, 0, 0, px);
    bitmapField.setPadding(xyEdges);
    vertical.invalidate();
    return super.navigationMovement(dx, dy, status, time);
}
}
```

Comment: I already gave a comment on code that where you put your map image; see the code once; Have any doubt come on following chat room:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937674/draggable-bitmapfield-in-blackberry/8939113#8939113
Here somany are there to give solutions

Comment: I wanted to ask that.. how to get this map as an image..??

Comment: Do you have any sample url to get the map from the server then I will provide you to how to get the map from server and convert it into Bitmap; Up to now I thought that you want a Movable image; That's why I don't put brain on that;

Comment: I am not specific about adding the MapField or map image. I need to try out. i am adding a mapfield and at some specific coordinate I am adding a bitmap. Now I need to drag this bitmapfield on top of the mapfield(like you can drag in google maps A & B positions)..but not able to take any action on the Bitmap..

Comment: Then how can you get the map image; and what is your requirement swati?

Comment: come on this chat room:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java